# Replace Series Of Bytes in File

Tags: c#

I'm making a program that will patch upk files to replace "4f 4c 44 6f 6f 72" with "4f 4c 52 6f 6f 72" in about 186 files ("4f 4c 44 6f 6f 72" has multiple occurences in each file).

I've seen a lot of guides on how to do this but they all require an offset of where the original bytes are which means I would need about 28 offsets for each file which would take way too long...

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Is the offset fixed and known? The "worst efficency" algorithm would be to linearly go through each file, found the sequence and replace it. Does speed really matter when this is maybe a one-time operation?

Comment: I could figure out the offset of these but that would mean I would have to look for about 5000 of those and it is a one time operation so speed doesn't really matter

Answer (score 1):

If each file is *small enough* to fit RAM you can try reading the entire file, modifing it and writing back:

```
  private static IEnumerable<int> Offsets(byte[] data, byte[] toFind) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= data.Length - toFind.Length; ++i) {
      bool matched = true;

      for (int j = 0; j < toFind.Length; ++j)
        if (data[i + j] != toFind[j]) {
          matched = false;

          break;  
        }

      if (matched)
        yield return i; 
    }
  }

  private static void ModifyFile(String path) {
    byte[] toFind = new byte[] {0x4f, 0x4c, 0x44, 0x6f, 0x6f, 0x72 };

    byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(path);

    foreach(var offset in Offsets(data, toFind))
      data[offset + 2] = 0x52; // we want just one byte to update

    File.WriteAllBytes(path, data); 
  }
```